# Where can I find good examples of TDD in iOS code on the net?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tdd

What is a good source where such code is available (e.g., in GitHub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty good example video for iOS TDD is available here: http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-tdd/

The source code from this example is not available online, but this won’t be too useful anyways. Test Driven Development is about the development process, not the final result. By looking at the finished code you can’t learn anything about TDD.

Comment: ... I'd argue the code shows you exactly how to overcome the hurdles that you'll hit when you find bits of iOS that seem untestable. TDD can only work if the platform you're working with lets you have enough flexibility to test.